# Is it possible to obtain or calculate a pixel's x and y index for an image within Swift's Metalkit library functions?

Tags: swift, cgimage, metalkit

I'm trying to perform some logic on some pixels within an Image. Currently I'm using a brute force approach with CGImage which looks something like this:

```
for y in 0 ..< cgImage.height {
   for x in 0 ..< cgImage.width {
      if x == 20 && y == 300 {
         //TODO: Change pixel color to clear color.
      }
   }
}
```

However this approach is super slow and I was hoping to do something similar in Swift Metal to boost performance. In Swift Metal I can't figure out how to get a specific pixel's index within the function. thread_position_in_grid only returns me the x and y of the thread within the grid. Is there anyway to determine the X and Y of the current pixel being operated on?

Here is the metal function that I'm trying to create and convert from using CGImage looping to Metal GPU processing:

```
kernel void black (texture2d<float, access::read> inTexture [[texture(0)]],
               uint2 id [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
   if (id.x == 20 && id.y == 300){
       //TODO: Change pixel color to clear color.
   }
}
```

Comment: Posting as a comment because this isn't Metal, but it *should* work. It sounds like you are doing too much at the CPU end. When you are using a general kernel function, why not simply access `destCoord()`? It's already there to give you what you need. (I do this routinely and it's *not* close to being super slow.)

Answer (score 1):

Decided to post this as an answer also. If it's not, I'll gladly delete this.

```
kernel vec4 clearColorPixel (sampler image) {
    vec2 coord = destCoord();
    if (coord.x == 20. && coord.y == 300.) {
        // TODO: change pixel to clear color
    }
}
```

While I don't work primarily with Metal or textures, it seems that you are using the CPU to pass in `uint2 id` to your kernel. Simply pass in the pixel. This works well for me and isn't super slow.

Comment: I really like your answer, unfortunately I am still very new to using GPU functions and MetalKit. I've been trying to understand how samplers work in MetalKit and how to obtain the destCoords from the sampler passed in, but its still a work in progress for me. I'll keep this thread updated as I make more progress on it, for now I'm up voting the answer. Thank you for the help.